# How to enumerate frames by block?

Tags: beamer, numbering, block

I have many frames with multiple blocks and I want the number of the frames to increase by block, not by frame.How can I do that?

Below is an example of one of my frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[t]{aaa}
\only<1>{
\begin{exampleblock}{bbb}
\begin{itemize}
\item ccc
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}}

\only<2-3>{
\begin{exampleblock}{ddd}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-3> \textit{eee}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item fff
    \end{itemize}

\item<3> \textit{ggg}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item hhh
    \end{itemize}   
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}}


\only<4>{
\begin{exampleblock}{iii}
jjj
\end{exampleblock}
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

instead of appearing all with the same number I want each *only* have its own number.

Comment: Minimal working example?

Comment: Sorry, but it will be too long if I put what is inside the blocks :/

Comment: The content of your blocks does not matter, but please make a compilable MWE that the theme you are using.

Comment: the update is done.

Comment: Your MWE does not show any numbers which should be changed. Please include the theme you are using.

Comment: that is because it needs the style

Answer (score 1):

This can simply be achieved by showing the page instead of the frame number:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[pagenumber]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{........}
\only<1>{
\begin{exampleblock}{...}
\begin{itemize}
\item ....
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}}

\only<2-3>{
\begin{exampleblock}{...}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-3> \textit{....}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item ...
    \end{itemize}

\item<3> \textit{......}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item ......
    \end{itemize}   
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}}


\only<4>{
\begin{exampleblock}{.....}
....
\end{exampleblock}
}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: how is that work? can you explain more, please